# iis 7 disable windows auth

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I setup a test website on my IIS 7.5, I created a Web Application project in VisualStudio and set up a web site in a new application pool in Classic Pipeline Mode.

I have this line in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
192.168.50.142     dev.mybigdomain.org.uk
```

Now if I access my website with `http://localhost/testHello/Default.aspx` it works fine,
but when I try `http://dev.mybigdomain.org.uk/testHello/Default.aspx` I get a "Windows security" window asking for authentication, but if enter "administrator" and password it does not recognise them and just asks again.

How can I disable the authentication?

Answer (score 4):

Have you try to change the *web.config* authentication mode to *Forms* or *None*?

```
 <system.web>
...
 <authentication mode="Forms">
```

instead of

```
<system.web>
...
<authentication mode="Windows">
```