# Error 401.1 when trying to login

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a folder inside my web application which requires a login. In `web.config` I have the following:

```
<location path="Admin">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I can't login, it displays always the login dialogbox even the credentials are correct.

Anyone any ideas ?

Comment: post the code and the requested URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the answer:

[iis 7 disable windows auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634148/iis-7-disable-windows-auth)